# null point object using asset manager

Tags: android, libgdx

```
@Override
public void show()
{
    main = new MainClass();

    texture = main.manager.get("ball.png");

    mainActor = new MainActor(world, texture, new Vector2(1,2));
    stage.addActor(mainActor);
}
```

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

how to fix it?

"manager" is the AssetManager created on my MainClass

my MainClass

```
public class MainClass extends Game
{
   protected AssetManager manager;

    @Override
    public void create()
    {

        manager = new AssetManager();

        manager.load("ball.png", Texture.class);
        manager.finishLoading();


        setScreen(new MainScreen(this));
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post your MainClass?

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive of course. See again Plz

Comment: I haven't used Java in a really long time but don't you need to change `manager = new AssetManager();` to `this.manager = new AssetManager();`? And also every other reference to `manager` in your MainClass needs to be `this.manager`

Comment: At what row you get that error?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating manager object inside `create()` method, but you are not calling that method. `create()` method is not constructor - it won't be called automatically. I don't know what Game class constructor does but most likely not it's not calling `create()`, but that method is called at some other occasion.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your first block of code is from within your MainScreen class. It doesn't make sense for your MainScreen to create a new MainClass Game instance. And since it is, you are referencing a MainClass instance that has never had `create()` called on it, so its `manager` is null.

Since I can see that your MainScreen class already takes an instance of MainClass, you just need to make sure it's storing it and you don't instantiate a new one. In this sort of case, I declare passed-in variables as `final` so I know they are not going to change (and it's impossible to change them accidentally).

```
public class MainScreen implements Screen {

    final MainClass main;

    public MainScreen(MainClass main){
        this.main = main;
    }

    //...

    @Override
    public void show()
    {
        texture = main.manager.get("ball.png");

        mainActor = new MainActor(world, texture, new Vector2(1,2));
        stage.addActor(mainActor);
    }

    //...

}
```